# Change Background Image and animate an UIButton when tapped iOS 7

Tags: ios, objective-c, uibutton, core-animation

I have an UIButton created by the following code

```
    button =  [UIButton buttonWithType:UIButtonTypeCustom];
    [button setImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"refresh_icon.png"] forState:UIControlStateNormal];
    [button setImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"reload_selected.png"] forState:UIControlStateSelected];
    [button addTarget:self action:@selector(buttonAction:)forControlEvents:UIControlEventTouchUpInside];
    [button setFrame:CGRectMake(0, 0, 20 , 20)];
```

Here when it's clicked the selector buttonAction is called and I am animating the button by a 360 degree rotation like this

```
- (void) buttonAction : (id) sender {
    NSLog(@"Reload Button Clicked");
    [self runSpinAnimationOnView:self.button duration:1.0 rotations:1.0 repeat:0];

}

- (void) runSpinAnimationOnView:(UIView*)view duration:(CGFloat)duration rotations:(CGFloat)rotations repeat:(float)repeat;
{
    CABasicAnimation* rotationAnimation;
    rotationAnimation = [CABasicAnimation animationWithKeyPath:@"transform.rotation.z"];
    rotationAnimation.toValue = [NSNumber numberWithFloat: M_PI * 2.0 /* full rotation*/ * rotations * duration ];
    rotationAnimation.duration = duration;
    rotationAnimation.cumulative = YES;
    rotationAnimation.repeatCount = repeat;

    [view.layer addAnimation:rotationAnimation forKey:@"rotationAnimation"];
}
```

It's working good but it's not that I actually want. I want that , when my button is clicked then button will take the image "reload_selected.png" (which I set for UIControlStateSelected) as background and then run the animation. When the animation is finished then button will have to return to it's actual background ("refresh_icon.png") again.

Can anyone suggest some change in code that will help me achieve the action I described above ? Thanks in advance for your help.

Answer (score 1):

Can you try like this,

```
[UIView animateWithDuration:YOURDURATION
            delay:0
            options:(UIViewAnimationOptionCurveLinear)
            animations:^ {
                          [button setImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"reload_selected.png"] forState:UIControlStateSelected];
                           button.transform = CGAffineTransformRotate(CGAffineTransformIdentity,M_PI * 2);
                         }
            completion:^(BOOL finished) {
                          [button setImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"refresh_icon.png"] forState:UIControlStateNormal];
                         }
    ];
```

Comment: I have tried this in the selector called buttonAction , but unfortunately it's not animating. This button has been set as a custom view in UIBarbuttonItem.

Comment: So you are trying to rotate a UIBarButtonItem ?. Is that so.

Comment: Yes , I am trying to do that.

Answer (score 0):

Instead of using Core Animation, you can use `animateWithDuration:animations:completion:` method of `UIView`. This method allows you to specify a completion block whick you can use to reset the image once the animation is completed.

EDIT:
Do something like

```
[view animateWithDuration:duration animations:^{
    //Do your animations here
} completion: ^(BOOL finished){
    if(finished) {
        //reset the image
    }
}];
```

To specify the animations you might want to animate the view's `transform` property using `CGAffineTransformRotate`.

Comment: Thanks for your answer. Can you suggest some sample code ?